# Connect to MySQL in MAMP

Tags: php, mysql, mamp

I'm trying to make a HTML form connect to a MySQL database on my MAMP.

However I'm not able to open the MySQL connection. I keep getting the message "Could not connect"

My thoughts for this -

1. The host is incorrect
2. The username and/or password is incorrect. I found this information in config.inc.php, so I believe it is correct, but there's a possibility ..

Here's the PHP script

```
<?php
class Database {
    function insert() {
        $dbhost = 'localhost:8888';
        $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, 'root', 'root');
        if (! $conn) {
            die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
        }
        else {
            echo "connected";
        }
    }   
}
```

?>

Comment: Have you tried echoing `$dbhost` from withing the function?

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Possible solutions from [this thread](http://forum.mamp.info/viewtopic.php?t=115):

a) Launch MAMP, go to Preferences and set **SQL Port** to **3306**.

b) Use this set of commands:

```
ps aux | grep mysql 
lsof -i 
killall -9 mysqld
```

in the Terminal and restart MAMP.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the default port for mySQL in MAMP is 8889 web server port is 8888