# PHP "database could not connect" MAMP

Tags: php, mysql, database, connection, mamp

I'm trying to use php to add a table to a database I created in MAMP.

I have explored these answers here:
[Cannot connect to mysql server with MAMP nor with Community Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6243631/cannot-connect-to-mysql-server-with-mamp-nor-with-community-server)
[Connect to MySQL in MAMP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16550942/connect-to-mysql-in-mamp)

I have also tried using this code on a server, this free hosting site called. biz.nf.  There I get no connection error, but the table is not created.

Really stumped here, would appreciate any advice, thanks.

```
<?php

$con = mysql_connect("localhost:3306", "paul", "paul");
mysql_select_db("magusblog", $con);

$table = "ENTRIES";
mysql_query("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS '$table' ( 'ID' INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , PRIMARY KEY ( 'ID' ) )");
mysql_query("ALTER TABLE '$table' ADD 'PHOTO' TEXT NOT NULL");
mysql_query("ALTER TABLE '$table' ADD 'TITLE' TEXT NOT NULL");
mysql_query("ALTER TABLE '$table' ADD 'DATE' TEXT NOT NULL");
mysql_query("ALTER TABLE '$table' ADD 'CONTENT' TEXT NOT NULL");

?>
```

Comment: If this is a new project, please do not use the mysql_* functions, as they have been deprecated. You should use [mysqli](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead.

Comment: @PatrickQ - don't you mean mysqli ? - And he's right - use mysqli instead - PDO is a bit harder, but it is also more portable - You might want to look into ORMs like idiorm, propel, or doctrine.

Comment: @rm-vanda Yup. Typo.  Edited.

Comment: so just use mysqli_connect and mysqli_select_db instead?  I just tried that and still got the same could not connect error, I'll look into PDO too.

Comment: Thanks Patrick, Mark B, Michael Budd, was banging my head against the wall.  Correcting those syntax errors solved the problem, and thanks for the tip about using or die(mysql_error()) as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of your queries have syntax errors. You do **NOT** use `'` quotes to delimit field names. If you'd bothered actually CHECKING if errors were occuring, you'd have been informed about this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS '$table' ( 'ID' INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , PRIMARY KEY ( 'ID' ) )
                           ^--    ^-- ^--^---                                          ^--^-
```

remove ALL of the indicated quotes, on ALL of your queries. And then rewrite them as:

```
$result = mysql_query(...) or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Thank you so much, correcting the syntax errors fixed the problems.  Now I will never mistake a backtick for a ' again.  Thanks for the tip about or die(mysql_error()) as well.  I thought they would just show up in the firefox web console.

Answer (score 0):

Was just a couple of syntax issues... see below.. just tested and successfully created the table. Let me know if any problems.

```
<?php

$table = "ENTRIES";
mysql_query("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " . $table . " (ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , PRIMARY KEY ( ID ) )");
mysql_query("ALTER TABLE " . $table . " ADD PHOTO TEXT NOT NULL");
mysql_query("ALTER TABLE " . $table . " ADD TITLE TEXT NOT NULL");
mysql_query("ALTER TABLE " . $table . " ADD DATE TEXT NOT NULL");
mysql_query("ALTER TABLE " . $table . " ADD CONTENT TEXT NOT NULL");
?>
```